# mdbtools won't install, breaks yay -Syyu

Tags: arch-linux

I just ran `yay -Syyu` and ended up with this message:

```
:: installing mdbtools (0.9.4-2) breaks dependency 'mdbtools=0.7.1' required by gmdb2
```

I get the same message when running `yay -S mdbtools`.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?  It appears that mdbtools 0.9.4-2 replaced mdbtools 0.7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options

1. remove gmdb2

> pacman -Rns gmdb2

2. exclude mdbtools from update

> sudo pacman -Syu --ignore mdbtools